# What is the distribution of the integral of a exponentially distributed random variable?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I have a random variable that is exponentially distributed, and the mean is $F$. It is actually a power spectral density at a frequency $\omega$. So, at each $\omega$, the power spectral density (PSD) $Z$ is exponentially distributed with mean $F(\omega)$. Can I theoretically find what will be the distribution of the total power under the PSD?

In short, what will be the distribution of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Z(\omega) d\omega $ ?

%% =========== EDIT ===========

The PDF of Z is:

$$ p(Z) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\pi F(\omega_n)} e^{-\frac{Z(\omega_n)}{F(\omega_n)}}, $$

where, $\omega_n$ are the frequency points. So, the following can be said about the expected value of $Z$.

$$ \mathbb{E}[Z(\omega)] = F(\omega) $$

The function $F$ looks like the following:

$$ F(\omega) = \frac{M}{\sqrt{2 \pi} s} \exp\left( - \frac{(\omega - \mu)^2}{2 s^2} \right) $$

I want to know the PDF of $P = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Z(\omega) d\omega$. A numerical simulation suggests that it is a Gaussian distribution, but I am not sure yet.

I tried calculating the moments:

$$ \mathbb{E}[P] =  \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Z(\omega) d\omega\right]$$

$$   = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb{E}[Z(\omega)] d\omega $$

$$   = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(\omega) d\omega $$

$$   = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(\omega) d\omega $$

$$   = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(\omega) d\omega = M $$

The variance:

$$ \mathbb{V}\left[P\right] = \mathbb{E}[P^2] - (\mathbb{E}[P])^2 $$

$$ = \mathbb{E}[P^2] - M^2 $$

I am stuck here. How to perform

$$ \mathbb{E}[P^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} Z(\omega) d\omega \right)^2 \right] $$

From numerical simulations, I can see that the variance of $P$ is inversely proportional to $s$. I don't know how this comes about theoretically.

Comment: It depends on the details.  At this point not much more can be said apart from "just calculate it."

Comment: I will add details. I have proceeded to some extent.